# Additional \ appearing in front of newline character(\n) when print Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Ihave this Python code:

```py
# # RSA Key
print('Enter the RSA key: ')
keyphrase = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        keyphrase.append(line)
    else:
        break
rsa_key = repr('\n'.join(keyphrase)).replace("'", "")
rsa_key = rsa_key + '\\n'
print(f'rsa_key: {rsa_key}')
output['key']['value'] = rsa_key
print(f"rsa_key_from_dict: {output['key']['value']}")
print(f"full_dict: {output}")
```

The output is as follows(please note, I've only included a snippet of the output from each print statement):

```
rsa_key: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAwfR7zzPpS3U6O4iCOdcTSKkYXq8Qa6Fs4WbWNQcGOYb1gBw5\nmPfnDq

rsa_key_from_dict: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAwfR7zzPpS3U6O4iCOdcTSKkYXq8Qa6Fs4WbWNQcGOYb1gBw5\nmPfnDq

full_dict: {'key': {'type': 'pulsar-athenz', 'additional_parameters': {'pulsar_athenz': {}}, 'id': 'fef', 'value': '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAwfR7zzPpS3U6O4iCOdcTSKkYXq8Qa6Fs4WbWNQcGOYb1gBw5\\nmPfnDq
```

You'll see that for the `rsa_key` and `rsa_key_from_dict` there is only one `\` before the `n`, denoting a newline character `\n` but in `full_dict` an additional `\` is inserted giving `\\n`.

Why is this additional `\` appearing and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing data and representation (see [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)). The string `'\n'` represents a newline character, while the string `'\\n'` represents a backslash `\` then a letter `n`. The backslash is an escape character, which is why it needs to be doubled when representing itself.

> You'll see that for the `rsa_key` and `rsa_key_from_dict` there is only one `\` before the `n`, denoting a newline character

Here `\n` doesn't represent a newline character, it is literally a backslash then a letter `n`

> but in `full_dict` an additional `\` is inserted giving `\\n`.

Here you're seeing the representation, `'\\n'`

Example:

```
>>> print('\n')  # newline


>>> print('\\n')  # backslash, n
\n
>>> print(repr('\\n'))  # representation of backslash, n
'\\n'
```

Comment: Ah OK. I'm just discovering `repr()`. Is there any way I can  print `full_dict` so it only has one `\`?

Comment: @runner One backslash? I think your comment got eaten by Markdown, which also uses backslash as an escape character btw. It seems like the problem isn't the representation, it's the data. You want to join the RSA key on newlines, but what your script effectively does is join it on backslash-n's.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm trying to join on new lines but I also want to include the `\n` characters in the join.

Comment: @runner Why would you want to include the backslash-n's when you want to join on newlines?

Comment: That is the format in which the third party app I'm sending it to requires.

Comment: Figured it out. I changed `rsa_key = repr('\n'.join(keyphrase)).replace("'", "")` to `rsa_key = '\n'.join(keyphrase).replace("'", "")` and `rsa_key = rsa_key + '\\n'` to `rsa_key = rsa_key + '\n'`. Cheers for the help. `repr` is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the subtle difference between `repr` and `str`.

> **repr**(*object*)
>
> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval() [...]

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#repr

Following up on your `'\\n'` example.

```py
>>> print('\\n')
\n
>>> print(repr('\\n'))
'\\n'
```

By default, variables passed to `str.format` will format with `str`. You can format it with `repr` by suffixing the variable name with `!r`.

```py
print(f'rsa_key: {rsa_key!r}')
```

String representations of dictionaries use `repr` to format their values. That's why you see the double backslashes when you print the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this dictionary object below.

```
dict = {
    'a':"\\nSomeValue", 
    'b':"\nSomeNewValue"
}
```

Now directly printing dictionary print(dict) will print this.

```
{'a': '\\nSomeValue', 'b': '\nSomeNewValue'}
```

And printing value separately as shown below

```
for key , value in dict.items():
    print(value)
```

it will print this.

```
\nSomeValue

SomeNewValue
```

This is because "\n" character is added with escape sequence to the string for key "a" hence it is added as it is and is part of that string value.